# Trimming more than needed off url in php

Tags: php

I am entering URL's into my database and i was getting all possible entries

I have the following code that takes the `http://` or `http` or `www`  `.com` `.co.uk` away

but the problem is this

when I enter a site like hat.com its taking the 'h' away this happens with t, p, w, and if its .co.uk it only removes the .uk

```
$new = rtrim($url, "/");

$reverse = strrev( $new );
$new = rtrim($reverse, ".www");
$new = rtrim($reverse, "//:ptth");
$new = rtrim($reverse, ".www//:ptth");
$new = rtrim($reverse, "//:sptth");
$new = rtrim($reverse, ".www//:sptth");
$url = strrev( $new );
```

Whats have I missed and what would I have to add?

Comment: Have you checked what the second argument for `rtrim` means? http://php.net/rtrim

Comment: The [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) functions do not remove sub-strings; they remove *characters*.

Comment: is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: removing sub domains seems like a bad idea `www.site.com` and `abc.site.com` may be unrelated. and of course the `.com`, `.co.uk ` is even worse - what are you going to do with this data

Comment: http://au2.php.net/parse_url

Comment: What is this madness?  Why are you reversing strings and all this?  I HIGHLY suggest you look at `parse_url()` function for a simple way to work with the various parts of a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression will help here:

```
preg_replace('~(^https?(://(www\.)?)?|\.com$|\.co\.uk$)~', '', $url);
```

The regular expression used will match:

- `http`, `https`, `http://`, `https://`, `http://www.`, `https://www.` at the beginning of the string
- `.com`, `.co.uk` at the end of the string.

See this example:

```
php> $url = 'https://www.example.com';
'https://www.example.com'
php> preg_replace('~(^https?(://(www\.)?)?|\.com$|\.co\.uk$)~', '', $url);
'example'
php> $url = 'http://hat.com';
'http://hat.com'
php> preg_replace('~(^https?(://(www\.)?)?|\.com$|\.co\.uk$)~', '', $url);
'hat'
```